# Change color of a dynamic textfield problem

Tags: flash, actionscript, function, actionscript-2, textfield

I have this code that should change the color of a dynamic textfield when I rollover the link movieclip, and then back when I rollout. I get no compiler error, it just doesn't work.

```
function textColor(mc_function:MovieClip, tf_text:TextField) {
mc_function.onRollOver = function() {
    tf_text.textColor = 0x7cb0b7; 
};
mc_function.onRollOut = function() {
    tf_text.textColor = 0xffffff; 
};
}

boxLink(link_a1,text_a1);
boxLink(link_a2,text_a2);
boxLink(link_a3,text_a3);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SetMouseAction(pMovieClip, pTextField):Void {
    pMovieClip.linkedText = pTextField;
    pMovieClip.onRollOver = function() {
            this.linkedText.textColor = 0x7cb0b7; 
    };
    pMovieClip.onRollOut = function() {
            this.linkedText.textColor = 0xffffff; 
    };
}

SetMouseAction(link_a1, text_a1);
SetMouseAction(link_a2, text_a2);
SetMouseAction(link_a3, text_a3);
```

at least I have tested it and it works for me

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can simplify the code, like getting rid of the repeating SetMouseAction() ? Something automatic?

Comment: for (var i:Number=1;i<=3;i++) {
 SetMouseAction(_root["link_a" + i], _root["text_a" + i]);
}